# Partial update in ElasticSearch with JEST

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jest

I'm trying to use JEST to implement CRUD actions to ElasticSearch, and I've surveryed some articles, the method I found to do "**Update**" is "**Index**" another document with the same "**_id**", but I'll replace the whole document in that way.

I want to know is JEST capable to do "**Partial Update**"?

**Edit :**

I found there's an **Update** class which is in ***io.searchbox.core*** package that might help, but after I try this :

```
Update update = new Update.Builder(updateCameraString).index(this._IndexName).type(this._TypeName).id(id).build();
JestResult updateResult = this._JestClient.execute(update);
```

The content of `updateCameraString` is

```
{"Name":"test Added into Es, update again.","CreatedAt":"","ModifiedAt":"","UniqueId":"","Note":""}
```

Seems everything is fine, but I'll get the response below :

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "action_request_validation_exception",
        "reason": "Validation Failed: 1: script or doc is missing;"
      }
    ],
    "type": "action_request_validation_exception",
    "reason": "Validation Failed: 1: script or doc is missing;"
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

Any device could be really appreciate, Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're almost there, the `updateCameraString` needs to either be a script or a partial document, so it needs to be changed to the following and it will work:

```
{"doc": { "Name":"test Added into Es, update again.","CreatedAt":"","ModifiedAt":"","UniqueId":"","Note":""}}
```

Comment: You're right! It works perfectly after I change the original string to the form you mentioned. I was really almost there, thank you so much for pushing me far away!!